# Iterate through worksheets in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, loops, iteration, openpyxl

I am trying to iterate through 6 worksheets and apply a specific format in a range of cells. I have already searched for similar issues and the proposed method I find is to import load_workbook from openpyxl. However, to apply this method I must have a workbook that is specifically named, so as to load it. My algorithm creates the workbook and then saves it, so there is no saved workbook to load. The part of the algorithm that I am trying to apply to iterate through worksheets is the one provided below.

```
 for i in range(1,6):
        for row in ws[i].iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                cell.style = style1
        for cell in ws[i]["1:1"]:
            cell.style = style2
```

This appears to have an issue on

`ws[i].iter_rows():`

and on

```
ws[i]["1:1"]:
```

part.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your workbook by `workbook.worksheets`.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "ABC"

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print (sheet)
    #do whatever you need to...
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, as I mentioned in the question, I do not have a saved workbook to load it. My code first creates the workbook and then saves it. So this option with load workbook is not possible to use.

Comment: The `load_workbook` part is not required actually. You already create the `Workbook` object which you can loop through using `wb.worksheets`